# How do we know there is a probability space that can support any number of arbitrary random variables defined upon it?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let's say we have a sequence of independent random variables all defined on the same underlying probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}):$

$$X_i:\Omega \to E_i \subset \mathbb{R}$$

With the above setup, each $X_i$ will have its own distribution $P_i$ defined on  the measurable space $\left(E_i,\mathcal{B}(E_i)\right)$,  which is the *pushforward measure* created by $X_i$ acting on  $\mathbb{P}$:

$$P_i(X_i\in B) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(B)),\;\;B\in \mathcal{B}(E_i)$$

Therefore, the value of $P_i$ is dependent on the underlying probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.

Put another way, it seems that my choice for $P_i$ **constrains** $\mathbb{P}$, (assuming I'm defining $P_i$ and simply seek a consistent $\mathbb{P}$

**Here's my confusion**

I see how this can work for one random variable and associated pushforward measure:

$$X_i \sim P_i \implies \mathbb{P}(A) =P_i(X(A)),\;\;A\in \sigma(X_i)$$

....but how do we know that there is a $\mathbb{P}$ that can accommodate an infinite number of such constraints? It seems we are assuming the following:

$$\exists \mathbb{P}:\mathbb{P}(A) =P_i(X(A)),\;\;A\in \sigma(X_i)\;\;\forall i$$

Why isn't there is some combination of $P_i$ that will result in at least one set $Q \in \mathcal{F}$ where $\mathbb{P}(Q)$ is undefined (i.e., fails to be a proper set function).

Comment: Basically you can consider your $(P_i)_{i\ge1}$ as one measure on a bigger (product) space, to which will correspond a measure $\mathbb P$ on an abstract probability space $\Omega$.

Comment: @nejimban perfect! Yes! So a pushforward measure along an index set uses a cylinder set over the product space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use $(\mathcal{I},\mathcal{B}_{\mathcal{I}},\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{I}:=[0,1]$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure, as the underlying probability space to construct a countably infinite number of independent random variables $\{X_i\}$ having arbitrary distributions $\{P_i\}$. Specifically, consider a space-filling curve $\varphi:\mathcal{I}\to \mathcal{I}\times \mathcal{I}\times\cdots$ (see, e.g., Sections 6.9 and 7.5 [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387942650)). The coordinate functions, $\{\varphi_i\}$, are independent uniform random variables. Then, set $X_i=F_i^{-}(\varphi_i)$, where $F_i(x)=P_i((-\infty,x])$ and $F_i^{-}$ is its generalized inverse.